# Bluetooth Classic V2.1 and BLE

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I was wondering if anyone could tell me why it is possible that my blood pressure monitor which runs with Class 1 v2.1 Bluetooth can pair and get values from a smartphone with API 23 with code that uses Bluetooth Low Energy?

```
  <uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
    android:required="true" />
```

I read that these were not compatable Blutooth versions however it works for me. Sorry my English is not good

Answer (score 0):

Since you have

```
  <uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
    android:required="true" />
```

It means that you have at least this one

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
```

Which is enough for BT v2.1 to be used. If your device is v2.1 as you claim, it will work even if you remove BLE feature from the manifest since it doesn't need it.